# Difference between Collections.sort(list) and Collections.sort(list,comparator)

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator, comparable

What's the difference between:

```
    public FlyingRabbit(){
        list = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
    }
    public void sort(Comparator<Sellable> comp) {
        Collections.sort(list, comp);
    }
```

and:

```
public class CompareCategory implements Comparator<Sellable> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Sellable s1, Sellable s2) {
            return (s1.getCategory()).compareTo(s2.getCategory());
    }
}
```

I'm confused about why do I need to use the Comparator `comp` instead of using `compare` inside `CompareCategory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collections.sort(List<T>)` sorts the given `List` by the [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) of its elements. The natural ordering of an object can be defined by implementing the `Comparable` interface in the corresponding class. This interface provides a single method, `compareTo`, which returns

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

On the other hand, `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<T>)` orders the `List`'s elements according to the given `Comparator`. Their natural ordering will be ignored for the sorting. This second method comes in hand when the `List`'s elements already possess their natural ordering but we want to order them by a different criteria.

Here's a simple example with a `Person` class displaying name, last name and age.

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name, lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        //Defining Person's natural ordering by creating a comparator and comparing by last name and then name the current object and the given paramter 
        return Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getName).compare(this, o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %d", name, lastName, age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Person("Matt", "O'Brien", 30),
                new Person("Conan", "O'Brien", 25),
                new Person("Frank", "Johnson", 50)
        ));

        //Original unordered list
        System.out.println(list);

        //List ordered by Person's natural ordering (last name and then name)
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

        //List ordered by custom criteria (age)
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me repeat my understanding. From the code you have given, is it mean that normal one  comparing the last name first then compare the first name to sort it out but the comparator one continued to sort the old one ( the one that already sorted last name and name ) by ordering number?

Comment: @Nooboolean exactly. The first `Collections.sort(List)` sorts the unordered list by last name and then name. At this point, the second `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` takes the previously ordered list (by last name and name) and  orders it by age.

Comment: But.. What's the difference between comparing the last name first and comparing the first name first  
@Dan

Comment: @Nooboolean those two orderings stacked mean that the list is first ordered by last name and for same values of last name it is ordered by name. As you can see, there are two O'Brien in the list: Matt and Conan. Even though Matt has been placed before Conan, after the ordering Conan is placed before Matt.

Comment: So that's mean if they got the same last name they will be continue to compare at first name right? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nooboolean yes. that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

If Sellable implements the interface Comparable you can use Collections.sort(list).
Otherwise you should create own Comparator and use Collections.sort(list, comparator). Because there must be a rule by which to compare elements of the Sellable type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a *comparator* when objects contained in the list implement `Comparable` interface.

#### Comparator & Comparator

That's how the purpose of this interface defined by the [*documention*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
> that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the **class's
> natural ordering**, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as
> its natural comparison method.

On the other hand, *comparator* - is an object that is used to provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a *natural ordering*, i.e. there's no obvious specific way in which these object can be ordered, and their class doesn't implement `Comparable`.

Comparators are handy when objects are required to be ordered in differently depending on the situation. For instance, you have a class `Student`, and students can be sorted by their names, ids, grades, etc. And you can create a comparator for each of these cases either by creating a class implementing the interface `Comparator` and overrides method `compare()` (like in the code you've listed) or by making use of the static methods like `Comparator.comparing()` introduced with Java 8.

With that said, interfaces `Comparator` and `Comparable` serve the same purpose (to facilitate comparison of object), but have different use cases.

***Caution:*** don't mix things together by creating a *comparator* **inside** the `compareTo()` method, as it's shown in another answer. It's a terrible idea. Why? Because such an implementation will create a **new comparator** for every invocation of this method. To sort a list of `10.000.000` elements, `10.000.000 * log(10.000.000)` comparisons will be required, with each comparison `compareTo()` will be called and a new instance of *comparator* will be created. It'll have a negative impact on the application performance because creation of objects is costful, it requires memory allocation and then gives loads of work to the garbage collector.

#### Fluent sorting

In order to sort a list, you can use static methods `sort()` from the `Collections` utility class, that are part of the JDK since the very early version. And you could find lots code-snippets on the Internet, where `Collection.sort()` is being used.

With Java 8 method [List#sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) was introduced in the `List` interface and you no longer need to resort to static methods from the `Collections` class. Instead you can directly invoke method `sort()` on the list, note that it always expects a comparator as an argument. If elements of the list implement `Comparable` you should pass `null` instead:

> If the specified comparator is `null` then all elements in this list
> must implement the `Comparable` interface and the elements' **natural
> ordering** should be used.

```
myList.sort(null); // only if element of the implement Comparable
```